# android : bluetooth connexion fail due to socket

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm trying to use bluetoothSocket to connect between my computer and my Android app on my phone

```
private void ConnectThread_BT(BluetoothDevice device) {
BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
mmDevice = device;
showToast("connectthread");
try {
    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

} catch (IOException e) { }
mmSocket = tmp;
showToast(mmSocket.toString());
} 

public  void run_BT() {
//btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
showToast("runbt");
try {
    mmSocket.connect();
    showToast("connect");
} catch (IOException connectException) {
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
        showToast(connectException.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException closeException) { }
    return;
}
```

I get the exception "failed socket might closed or timeout, read ret :-1"... Has anyone ever fixed this problem?

Thanks. Have a Nice day

Comment: You say that you're trying to connect to your computer, are you running your own bluetooth server application on your computer? If so what are you using?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Actually I have windows 8.1 so I go in "bluetooth parameters" where I see myphone as paired. I tried to connect with another phone and it did the same...

Comment: Okay, so do you want to send any data to your computer through your phone via an android app? Or do you just want the two to connect?

Comment: Thx. I want the two of them to connect, and then I will need them to share data. The goal is to use this app with an Arduino, which is going to send the temperature of a room etc..